# TypeError "null has no properties" when adding controls

Tags: javascript, here-api

nokia newbie here.

I have added simple (from sample) code to display a map with the various controls on it.
The map displays ok but non of the controls display and the error "TypeError: null has no properties" error displays in the console.

I have tried things like adding the controls one at a time but adding any control generates the error.

I have searched for this but not found anything. It has to be really simple surely.

An excerpt from the code is below.
Any help would be appreciated

```
{

    nokia.Settings.set("app_id", "myid"); 
    nokia.Settings.set("app_code", "mycode");
    // Use staging environment (remove the line for production environment)
    nokia.Settings.set("serviceMode", "cit");
    (document.location.protocol == "https:") &&
                    nokia.Settings.set("secureConnection", "force");
    var mapContainer = document.getElementById(mySelf.options["id"]); 
    // Create a map inside the map container DOM node

            if(mySelf.options["controls"] == true){
                controls = [
                new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(), 
                new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.Traffic(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.PublicTransport(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.DistanceMeasurement(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.Overview(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar(),
                new nokia.maps.positioning.component.Positioning(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.ContextMenu(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomRectangle(),
                new nokia.maps.map.component.TrafficIncidents()
              ];
            } else {
                controls = [
                           ];
            }
            this.map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
                center: [52.51, 13.4],
                zoomLevel: 10,
                components: controls

         });
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? What is `mySelf`?

Comment: The error is in base.js line 297. 
{
     mySelf = this;
}

Comment: TypeError: null has no properties
https://js.cit.api.here.com/ee/2.5.4/base.js
Line 297
use:function(){},g:function(a){this.li(a)},Jn:function(a){var c=b.FontHelper.parse;this.re||(this.re={});var f=this.re[a];f||(f=this.re[a]=c(a));return f},Re:function(a,c){var f,k=ovi.type(a),d;if(k==="string")f=(d=nokia.maps.util.Sf(a)).documentElement;else if(k==="document"&&a.documentElement)f=(d=a).documentElement;ovi.type(f)!=="element"&&b.d("svgMarkup needs to be a valid SVG string or XML document!");this.M=c||new p;this.mi(f);return d},parseSvg:function(a){this.Re(a);return this.M.getIDL()},

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The map api looks at a global variable called self. I was setting a self=this with out var in front in one of my functions. The map api really got its knickers in a twist. Took me hours to find this. Hope it helps someone else.